# How do I correct this query that contains a subquery in db2?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a query that i use in db2 as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(
    SELECT
    DD.NAME
    FROM
    DIVISIONTABLE DD
    WHERE
    DD.DIVISION_ID=ll.DIVISION_ID 
    fetch first 1 rows only
    ) AS LASTNAME 
-- few more attributes that do not use a subquery as above

FROM
    lineTable ll
    WHERE
    ll.id = 113835
    GROUP BY
(ll.attr1, ll.attr2)
```

The problem is that if i remove the subquery above, the query works fine.
I get this error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-119, SQLSTATE=42803, SQLERRMC=DIVISION_ID that states "A COLUMN OR EXPRESSION IN A HAVING CLAUSE IS NOT VALID". But I haven't used a having clause anywhere. So I'm unable to understand this error.

Comment: Columns referenced in the `GROUP BY` clause must be present in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: I'm adding the aggregate function "min" before select..sorry forgot to mention